# Testing ARC zip on chromebook

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I used ARC-welder to test the app on my PC and create a zip - now I am searching a way to test this zip on a chromebook without publishing it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one recipe that worked for me:

Step #1: UnZIP it into a directory on a thumb drive, SD card, or other removable storage that your Chromebook supports

Step #2: Plug in that drive/card/whatever into your Chromebook

Step #3: On the Chromebook, in Chrome, in `chrome://extensions`, check the "Developer Options" checkbox

Step #4: Click the "Load Unpacked Extension..." button, browse to your removable storage, and choose the directory that you created in step #1

Step #5: If Step #4 complains about something related to `import`, install [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) on the Chromebook itself, which will have the side effect of installing the ARC extension, then try Step #4 again

Step #6: Run your app, which should show up in the Chromebook's app launcher thingy

Comment: Thanks a lot - that sounds legit - that's why I accepted the answer - unfortunately I fail at #5 as I cannot find ARC-Welder in the store ( on my PC yes, but not on the Chromebook )

Comment: @ligi: Check `chrome://version` and confirm that you are on 41. Also, I cannot find ARC Welder via a search of the Chrome Web store, but the link in the answer works. For example, I got ARC Welder on my Chromebook by tying in the URL for [the "Getting Started with ARC" page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) and clicking on the ARC Welder link.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this but in general you should install ARC Welder on the chromebook and test there. The zip file that is generated by ARC Welder is meant to be uploaded to the chrome web store, and some development options are stripped out, like crx_key metadata. This means features like play services will not work properly when loaded by a zip file: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/arc_playservices

If you absolutely can't export on Chromebook, for instance you need a bundle to give to QA without requiring exporting, the better way is to zip up the export directory that was created by ARC Welder during test, and moving that to the Chromebook (share via Google Drive, email, or SD card / USB drive). This lives under the directory you chose when you first ran ARC Welder.

Another option is to publish to a [trusted tester group](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#testaccounts) and have the testers download from the web store. This will keep your app private but allow them to download it like normal users will, which will auto install ARC as needed, etc.